# How to create an immutable Map in Scala using foldings?

Tags: scala

I am trying to create an immutable hash Map[String, (String, Int)] using the following code:

```
def genList(xx: String) = {
    Seq("one", "two", "three", "four")
}

val oriwords = Set("hello", "how", "are", "you")

val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
        val xv = 2

        genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
            val src = cmap get ps

            if(src == None) {
                cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
            }
            else {
                if(src.get._2 < xv) {
                    cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
                }
                else cmap
            }

        })
    }
)
```

With this code I am getting the following exception:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)]]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)]
               genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
                                       ^
```

I know that it is returning a `list` of `Map[String, (String, Int)]` as opposed to an update for `Map[String, (String, Int)]` for the fold operation. Unfortunately,
I am getting any pointers how to fix it. I am very new to Scala.

Expected output is:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)] = Map(one -> (are,2), two -> (are,2), three -> (are,2), four -> (are,2))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your output should look like?

Comment: Output should be a map[String, (String, Int)]. For example, in this case it would be, `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)] = Map(one -> (are,2), two -> (are,2), three -> (are,2), four -> (are,2))`

Comment: updated description as well as comment.

Comment: One way to fix the error is to change the `map()` call to a fold, but you still might not get the output you're looking for. `oriwords` is a `Set` and sets have no defined order, so the order of elements that appear in the fold operation is indeterminate and probably not the order you expect.

Comment: Order is not of concerned. I only intend to get the hash map of key value pairs.

Comment: So the difference between the expected `("are",2)` tuples (as commented above) and the actual `("hello",2)` tuples (as demonstrated below) is immaterial (at this point in the game)?

Comment: yes. The actual values does not matter. The logic will hold though and val `xv = 2` will be replaced by a query to get the value in runtime instead of just a 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using fold:

```
def genList(xx: String) = {
    Seq("one", "two", "three", "four")
}

val oriwords = Set("hello", "how", "are", "you")

val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
        val xv = 2

        genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
            val src = cmap get ps

            if(src == None) {
                cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
            }
            else {
                if(src.get._2 < xv) {
                    cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
                }
                else cmap
            }

        }).fold(Map[String, (String, Int)]())((a, b) => a ++ b)
    }
)
println(newMap) //Map(one -> (hello,2), two -> (hello,2), three -> (hello,2), four -> (hello,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator your `foldLeft` returns is of type `Seq[Map[String, (String, Int)]]` when it should be `Map[String, (String, Int)]`

As mentioned above the reason is because you are calling `map` on a `Seq` which returns a `Seq`. You can solve the problem by using foldLeft

```
  def genList(xx: String) = {
    Seq("one", "two", "three", "four")
  }

  val oriwords = Set("hello", "how", "are", "you")

  val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
      val xv = 2

      genList(currentWord).foldLeft(cmap) {
        (acc, ps) => {
          val src = acc get ps

          if (src == None) {
            acc + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
          }
          else {
            if (src.get._2 < xv) {
              acc + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
            }
            else acc
          }

        }
      }
    }
  )

  println(newMap)

Map(one -> (hello,2), two -> (hello,2), three -> (hello,2), four -> (hello,2))
```

However the output does not match the expected values so you will need to check your logic...