# Why this Scala code is apparently not running on the Spark workers instead only on the Spark driver node?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was using the code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371286/how-to-create-an-immutable-map-in-scala-using-foldings/53372180#53372180) to create an HashMap in Scala. Copy-pasting below for convenience:

```
def genList(xx: String) = {
    Seq("one", "two", "three", "four")
  }

  val oriwords = Set("hello", "how", "are", "you")

  val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
      val xv = 2

      genList(currentWord).foldLeft(cmap) {
        (acc, ps) => {
          val src = acc get ps

          if (src == None) {
            acc + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
          }
          else {
            if (src.get._2 < xv) {
              acc + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
            }
            else acc
          }

        }
      }
    }
  )

  println(newMap)
```

**Note**: The above code works for small `oriwords`, however, it does not work when `oriwords` is large. Apparantly because the computations are happening at the Spark driver node.

When I run, I get the the out of memory exception as follows:

```
 WARN  HeartbeatReceiver:66 - Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 159099 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-1"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-1"
Exception in thread "refresh progress" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How to force the calculation to happen on the Spark cluster and save the generated HashMap on the Spark cluster itself instead of it being calculated and saved at the Spark driver node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things need to be in `RDD`, `Dataset`, `Dataframe` et al. for spark to distribute your computations. basically everything happens on the driver except for things that are in HoFs like `map` and `foreach` on one of those structures.

Comment: Where is a Map get's stored? At the Spark driver or across the Spark cluster? Since, it is neither RDD, Dataset or Dataframe.

Comment: just on the driver. distribution only happens based on the above listed types *not* for scala std-lib `Map`

Comment: So you are saying that we cannot have a distributed HashMap on Spark written on Scala?

Comment: well there are technologies that give you key-value based storage with fast random order lookup (e.g. redis or hbase). and you can certainly work with key-value RDDs. what do you want to do, what's the property of Map you want?

Comment: I am building this hashmap for spell check lookup. I am expecting it to be very big ~12*10^9 words.

Comment: so I'm going to assume a couple things here but broadly I'd use something like redis here and executor-local fixed size caches. else you'd have to keep the whole word list in memory all the time at each executor.

Comment: I want to keep all the word list in memory only for fast lookup. When you say, "you'd have to keep the whole word list in memory all the time at each executor" did you mean that each executor will have the same

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses the DataFrame and RDD abstractions to represent data. It doesn't use Scala Maps. So you need to wrap your data in an RDD or DataFrame (preferred option). Depending on the type of data you have there are different methods to load the data.